# Rails cron Whenever gem error, bundle: command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, cron, whenever

I've read this post [Whenever errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482298/rails-cron-whenever-bundle-command-not-found)  and tried to implement the recommendations to no avail. I'm still receiving '/bin/bash: bundle: command not found' error.
On Amazon EC2.

which ruby

```
/usr/local/bin/ruby
```

which bundler

```
/usr/local/bin/bundler
```

schedule.rb

```
env :PATH, ENV['PATH']
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)
set :output, "log/cron_log.log"

every 1.minutes do
  rake "calculate:calculate"
end
```

crontab -e

- - - - - /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /srv/www/myapp/releases/20141022032959 && RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake calculate:calculate --silent >> log/cron_log.log 2>&1'

tail -f log/cron_log.log

```
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
```

When I copy the command out of crontab and run it directly, everything works fine (cd /srv/www/myapp/releases/20141022032959 && RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake calculate:calculate --silent >> log/cron_log.log 2>&1). It's the prepending of /bin/bash that's messing this up.

How do I get schedule.rb / whenever gem to recognize correct PATH.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Forget about PATH settings in cron files.  Setting the PATH does not work.

Set the path to bundle explicitly in your config/schedule.rb

```
set :bundle_command, "/usr/local/bin/bundle exec"
```

**Edit: exec added so that task can run**

Comment: just tested it. shouldn't that actually be ``"/usr/local/bin/bundle exec"``?

Comment: Yes, the correct would be `"/usr/local/bin/bundle exec"`

Comment: The problem with this is that `schedule.rb` is generally versionned under git. From what we know, the path of `bundle` can change depending on machine. How do you handle it then?

Comment: @El-Key did you got the solution on the path change depending on machine. its really interesting coz one machine might have different path and another one different. is there any correct way to do this?

Comment: @VoidZero I added this `env :PATH, ENV['PATH']` at the beginning of the file `schedule.rb`

Answer (score 3):

If none of the above solution works this did it for me without any additional setup

```
rvm cron setup
```

This will include all the right paths for gems so you do this on your machine and you are good to go.

Answer (score 3):

If using rbenv, the path is "/home/YOUR_USER/.rbenv/shims/bundle", so you shoud write at the top of schedule.rb..:

```
set :bundle_command, "/home/YOUR_USER/.rbenv/shims/bundle exec"
```