# Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory ----- rvm | cron | ubuntu | whenever

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, cron, rvm, whenever

I'm using whenever and dynamic_sitemaps gems to generate sitemaps.

here's my **schedule.rb**

```
job_type :rake, "{ cd #{@current_path} > /dev/null; } && RAILS_ENV=:environment bundle exec rake :task --silent :output"
job_type :script, "{ cd #{@current_path} > /dev/null; } && RAILS_ENV=:environment bundle exec script/:task :output"
job_type :runner, "{ cd #{@current_path} > /dev/null; } && RAILS_ENV=:environment bundle exec rails runner ':task' :output"

set :output, "#{path}/log/cron.log"

every 1.day, :at => '5:30 am' do  
  rake "sitemap:generate"        
end
```

if I use "`bundle exec rake sitemap:generate RAILS_ENV="production"`" my sitemap is generated properly.

```
`bundle exec whenever RAILS_ENV="production"` seems to be working too
```

-

```
30 5 * * * /bin/bash -l -c '{ cd > /dev/null; } && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake sitemap:generate --silent >> /var/www/.*******.log 2>&1'

## [message] Above is your schedule file converted to cron syntax; your crontab file was not updated.
## [message] Run `whenever --help' for more options.
```

But when I check cron.log on another day(after 5:30) I see this message

```
Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory
```

So, the new sitemap wasn't generated. **How can I fix this?**

already tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482298/rails-cron-whenever-bundle-command-not-found) but it didn't work for me or I'm doing something wrong.

I installed ruby with **rvm**

---

**UPDATE**

So, I made it working. And here's what I did:

```
ls /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/
```

This gave me a list of wrappers/aliases that I have. One of them was `ruby-2.2.2`

then I edited my schedule.rb

```
set :output, "#{path}/log/cron.log"
job_type :runner, "cd #{path} && RAILS_ENV=production /home/$USER/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.2.2/bundle exec rails runner ':task' :output"

every 1.day, :at => '4:30 am' do
  rake "sitemap:generate"
end
```

and run `bundle exec whenever --update-crontab RAILS_ENV="production"` from the app directory(current).

**UPD 2017**

`rvm cron setup` might be helpful too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when cron is executed, it won't load the rvm environment. There are several approaches to solve this. The RVM documentation has all the information you need - https://rvm.io/deployment/cron

Answer (score 1):

It changed directory to home (`cd > /dev/null;`) since `@current_path` is nil.

It should work if you delete the first 3 lines. (https://github.com/javan/whenever/blob/master/lib/whenever/setup.rb)