# bundler: not executable: bin/rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to create a cron job that runs a model method with the whenever gem but i'm having trouble. I'm getting

**schedule.rb**

```
every 1.hours do
  runner "DailyAttendance.fetch_data"
end
```

I also ran the whenever --update-crontab to update the cron job.

**Error:** bundler: not executable: bin/rails

Comment: you have a problem with your env variables https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482298/rails-cron-whenever-bundle-command-not-found

Comment: thanks for your answer.

Comment: @SantoshKumbhar how you fixed this???